# Does BluetoothSelectDevices contain an MS bug?

Tags: c++, winapi, bluetooth, visual-c++-2008

So, I narrowed down the unpredictable crashes in my application to the **BluetoothSelectDevices** function. It is supposed to allow a device selection by the user.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <Bthsdpdef.h>
#include <BluetoothAPIs.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "bthprops")
#pragma comment(lib, "user32")

bool getDevice(void)
{
    BLUETOOTH_SELECT_DEVICE_PARAMS btsdp = { sizeof(btsdp) };

    btsdp.hwndParent = NULL; // hDlg; // "set to NULL for no parent."
    btsdp.fShowUnknown = TRUE;
//  btsdp.fAddNewDeviceWizard = TRUE;
    btsdp.fShowAuthenticated = TRUE;

    BOOL b = BluetoothSelectDevices( &btsdp );
    if ( b )
    {
//         BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO * pbtdi = btsdp.pDevices;
//         for ( ULONG cDevice = 0; cDevice < btsdp.cNumDevices; cDevice ++ )
//         {
//             if ( pbtdi->fAuthenticated || pbtdi->fRemembered )
//             {
//                 //
//                 //  TODO:      Do something usefull with the device info
//                 //
//             }
//
//             pbtdi = (BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO *) ((LPBYTE)pbtdi + pbtdi->dwSize);
//         }

        BluetoothSelectDevicesFree( &btsdp );
    }
    else
    {
        if (GetLastError() != ERROR_CANCELLED)
            MessageBox(NULL, "BluetoothSelectDevices failed.", "Error", MB_OK);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
int main(void){for (int i = 0; i < 10 && getDevice(); i++);return 0;}
```

It will eventually encounter an Access Violation, though it may run perfectly for a while (which is why I put it in a loop for easier testing.)

After a great deal of frustration, I  went to the "BluetoothAPIs.h" file and copied the code above almost verbatim as suggested by Microsoft!!  I even commented out the unessential parts.  Under VC9 the compile line is as simple as: "cl /ZI /RTCcsu main.cpp"

Perhaps someone can suggest what I'm doing wrong?

The debugger is of no help. It just shows failure in the Kernel at 0x6CD1DCD9. Setting all the parameters explicitly as I do below makes no difference.

```
memset(&btsdp, 0, sizeof(btsdp));
btsdp.dwSize = sizeof(BLUETOOTH_SELECT_DEVICE_PARAMS);
btsdp.cNumOfClasses = 0; // search for all devices
btsdp.prgClassOfDevices = NULL;
btsdp.pszInfo = L"Select Device..";
btsdp.hwndParent = NULL;
btsdp.fForceAuthentication = FALSE;
btsdp.fShowAuthenticated = TRUE;
btsdp.fShowRemembered = TRUE;
btsdp.fShowUnknown = TRUE;
btsdp.fAddNewDeviceWizard = FALSE;
btsdp.fSkipServicesPage = FALSE;
btsdp.pfnDeviceCallback = NULL; // no callback
btsdp.pvParam = NULL;
btsdp.cNumDevices = 0; // no limit
btsdp.pDevices = NULL;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you consider memsetting the whole structure to 0 as the first step of its initialization?

Comment: Alexey, thanks for your suggestion. Yes, I did try that, still the same.